Trying to display a piecewise function in a matplotlib.pyplot label
Latex works in a latex editor but not as plot label.I am graphing a function using matplotlib.pyplot and I am using latex for the label. I am graphing a piecewise function and I am trying to label it by what the function is. The '{' that should be covering both lines of the piecewise function is only covering the first row and the second row starts before even the first row starts. Furthermore does not work at all when using & to align the rows.
Expected

Got

Using:
pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=latex)
Python 3.10.5
Code
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl


mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
X_2a = np.arange(0.0, 100, 0.1)

def piecewise_function(input_time):
    model_output = np.where(50 > input_time, np.sqrt(input_time), input_time**1.01-44.9237)
    return model_output


plt.plot(X_2a, piecewise_function(X_2a), label=r'$m_e=\begin{cases} t<50, \quad \sqrt{t} \\ t \ge 20, \quad t^{1.01}-44.9237 \end{cases}$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


Does this answer your question? How to write your own LaTeX preamble in Matplotlib?

cases (not familiar with it) is probably part of a package that is not used.
Maybe just asmmath.
There is probably a way to force the inclusion of packages. Since matplotlib simply execute latex as external command, when usetex option is used, it should be able to do whatever latex can do.
But in the meantime my solution would be not to use it
r'$m_e=\left\{ \begin{array}{l} t<50, \quad \sqrt{t} \\ t \ge 20, \quad t^{1.01}-44.9237 \end{array} \right.$'

gives the same result, doing myself the cases job (which is not very complicated as you can see: just an array of two elements, with a { beginning.

